# golang participle panic with "panic: unexpected token XXX"

Tags: go, parsing, lexer

I am learning [participle](https://github.com/alecthomas/participle), a parser based on golang. After I went through the tutorial, I decided to create a simple Array parser, here's my construction.

First, I need an AST to represent this array. for the simplicity purpose, I only parse Array of string without quotation mark. (`{value1, value_two, value_3_here}`, e.t.)

```golang
type SimpleArray struct {
    Arr []Values `"{" @@* "}"`
}

type Values struct {
    Str string `@Ident`
}
```

and now I create a Lexer for the input string

```golang
var Lexer = stateful.MustSimple([]stateful.Rule{
    {`Ident`, `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_\d]*`, nil},
    {`punct`, `[}{,]`, nil},
    {`whitespace`, `\s+`, nil},
})
```

and I have my main function below, with a simple test case `s := "{key, value}"`

```golang
func main() {
    var parser = participle.MustBuild(&SimpleArray{},
        participle.Lexer(Lexer),
    )
    b := &SimpleArray{}
    s := "{key, value}"
    err := parser.ParseString("", s, b)
    if err != nil {panic(err)}
    repr.Println(b, repr.Indent("  "), repr.OmitEmpty(true))
}
```

But I got a panic.

```sh
panic: 1:2: unexpected token "key"
```

I think the `@Ident` in `Values` struct will catch the "key", but it isn't, why is it? and how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems that I see, the first being a rule definition syntax error, the second being an error with the rules themselves.

The parser is not able to parse anything, because the parser still needs to get a `{` token to begin the first rule `SimpleArray`. The reason why the first `{` token is not being passed through by the lexer is because the name of the rule `punct` should be capitalized `Punct`. Tokens in a lowercase rule (like `whitespace`) are read by the lexer, but not passed to the parser.

Additionally, there is another problem that is not letting you parse the commas. You need to modify the rule to allow for additional items which have the separating comma.

Change the following:

```golang
type SimpleArray struct {
    Arr []Values `"{" @@* "}"`
}
```

to:

```golang
type SimpleArray struct {
    Arr []Values `"{" (@@ ("," @@)*)? "}"`
}
```

An explanation of the new rule:

- `"{"` to parse the `{`
- `(...)?` to make the list optional (if this is what you actually want, if not remove this part)
- `@@ ("," @@)*` to recursively parse one or more items, separated by a comma
- `"}"` to parse the `}`

Comment: It make sense a little, but with my case, Isn't the lower case "punct" saying, if the parser sees "{", "}", "," just ignore them and continue. That way my solution would still work, isn't it?

Comment: @YiLuo The documentation states, "As a convenience, any Rule starting with a lowercase letter will be elided from output." So, the lexer reads it, but doesn't pass it to the parser. The parser, however is expecting those tokens. The lexer and parser are independent, so let me update my answer to provide clarification.